# BottomNavigation и swipe

Tags: android, material-design, design

Использую в приложении `Bottom navigation` и `ViewPager`. Переход по франгментам происходит по `swipe`-у или при нажатии на таб `Bottom navigation`. Является ли такой подход нарушением `google` `guidlines`? Искал информацию на оф. [сайте](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#anatomy) но ответа на свой вопрос не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я помню раньше да, в доке было написано что не следует соединять `BottomNavigation` с `ViewPager`.

Сейчас там нет прямого запрета, но есть предписание не использовать анимации перехода между экранами похожими на поведение `ViewPager`.

https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#behavior

Сам гугл, вроде, говорит, что `MATERIAL DESIGN` суть рекомендация, не закон. Т.е. его можно нарушать. Сам гугл иногда его нарушает в своих приложениях.